# Calling function of service. Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

It seems like im unable to get my service up and running in angular 6. im trying to call any function in CoreService, but it dont seem to work.

What is the cause?

Error:

```
  error TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'typeof CoreService'.
```

This is where im calling the CoreService function.

```
import { CoreService} from "./../core.service";

  CoreService.query('login','POST',{username: this.username, password: this.password}).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe((value) => {

        });
```

And here is my service:

```
import { throwError as observableThrowError, interval as observableInterval, Observable,  Subscription , Subject} from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CoreService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  result = {};
  permission = false;
  baseurl = environment.apiUrl;
  baseapi = this.baseurl + ':3000/api';
  options = {withCredentials: true};




  query(action,type,postdata) {

    // console.log("calling: " + type + " : " + action);
    if (type == 'POST') {
      return this.http.post(this.baseapi   + "/" + action, postdata ,this.options).pipe(
          map(result => result),
          tap(result => this.result = result),);



    } else {
      return this.http.get(this.baseapi + "/" + action, this.options).pipe(
          map(result => result),
          tap(result => this.result = result),);
    }

  }




  performLogin(name: string, password: string) {
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', name);
    params.append('password', password);

    return this.http.post(this.baseapi + '/login/login',params, this.options).pipe(
        map(result => result),
        tap(result => this.result = result),);
  }




}
```

What is causing this to occur?

Comment: That's not how you inject a service into a component. Have a look at the official [guide](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the service inside the constructor

**`constructor(private myservice:CoreService)`**

and then do,

```
this.myservice.query(login','POST',{username: this.username, password: this.password});
```

Comment: i will accept the answer as soon as i can. I really know this, but havent done things in a few months and really forgot it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call "query" method as a static method.

If you want to call like that, add `static` just before.

```
static query(action,type,postdata)
```

OR

Inject your service in a `constructor(yourService: CoreService)` and do :

```
this.yourService.query(....);
```